# Receiving HTTP header 406 error

Tags: php, dbpedia

I am trying to invoke http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles in PHP with HTTP headers for an educational assignment I have been given. It must be this URL i.e. I am not allowed to use the JSON URL directly.

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>"Accept: application/json"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles";
$data = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
echo $data;
?>
```

I'm facing this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Unacceptable.

Please help to get rid of this error. Note: I read about this error and found suggestions to use CURL. However, I don't want to go into installation of CURL. Kindly suggest using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I'm getting 200 in my browser, so just check it is up from your location. Maybe also it need a User Agent? You can supply a `stream_context` to do this with `file_get_contents`, see the PHP manual.

Comment: Could you just get [this JSON version](http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json) as per the links in the footer? `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks Halfer. But could you elaborate on User Agent? And I am required to use http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles URL.

Comment: The User Agent is a string that identifies your browser, and since your browser is PHP is this case, it will have its own string that may be blocked at the remote end. See the manual or a search engine for more details.

Comment: Why can you not use the JSON URL? That's a critical restriction that ought to be noted in your question directly, imo.

Comment: Well, its a small assignment wherein Professor has explicitly mentioned to use the URL mentioned in this question.

Comment: Ah, it's generally a good idea to explicitly mark homework or other educational assignments as such.

Comment: Hi, what did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

406 says that application/json is not available.

From Wikipedia:

406 Not Acceptable The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $data;
?>
```