# PHP message: PHP Warning: file_get_contents('url_here') failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: php, api, request, http-post

Im trying to get data from api [HERE](https://inventory.eciaauthorized.com/documentation/execute-search) via POST request to my application and it does return error in `error.log`.

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents('url_here') failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://inventory.api.eciaauthorized.com/api/Search/Query';
$fields = array(
  'CompanyID' => 'company_id',
    'APIKey' => 'api_key_here',
    'Queries' => array(
      'SearchToken' => 'query_string_here',
    ),
    'InStockOnly' => true,
    'ExactMatch' => true,
    'IsCrawler' => true
);

$postdata = http_build_query($fields);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json ' . ' Accept: application/json',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

When I var_dump the result it returns:

> false

What I am missing here? Please help. Thanks.

[From This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019600/warning-fopen-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-406-not-acce) who have answer It throws the same error.

```
$result = fopen($url, "r",true, $context);
```

Some suggest to user **CURL** so I do it this is my code:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
//execute post
$result['body'] = curl_exec($ch);
$result['headers'] = curl_getinfo($ch);

if(curl_error($ch))
{echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);}

var_dump($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

When I **var_dump** the $result it returns

> true

and there are no data included and it throws error on

> "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 06:43:54 GMT Content-Length: 0

Ive done my research on that error and see that the headers are incomplete but I follow properly the API documentation. Please Help. Thanks.

These are on the documentation:

> The ECIA Inventory API receives search requests via HTTP POST. It supports both JSON and XML requests and responses. Please indicate with your requests which format you would like to use by including the "Content-Type" and "Accept" headers set to either "application/json" or "application/xml".
>
> The format for the body of the requests and responses is defined
>   below. The url for the API is:
>   https://inventory.api.eciaauthorized.com/api/Search/Query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624407/receiving-http-header-406-error  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/why-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed   Or the last solution of marked answer here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019600/warning-fopen-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-406-not-acce

Comment: @Anant on yout last link that have answer..how to send data via POST using fopen? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Goper. glad to hear that

Comment: @Anant sir? it throws the same error $result = fopen($url, "r",true, $context); I use that code. Im new on this field sir thanks. Sorry for the disturb.

Comment: You'd better use cURL instead of `fopen()`. Remember to supply User Agent string

Comment: @Raptor i will try that now sir. Thanks.

Comment: @GoperLeoZosa can u provide credentials to test it